# C Code to Color Waveforms by Frequency

Tags: audio

I want to display audio waveforms color-coded in each part by the local frequency content.  Basically exactly what Serato/Traktor or any other DJ software does where you can look at the sound and tell what frequencies are there.  It looks like this: [image]

So essential I will do an FFT to get frequencies at whatever bin-width I specify, but can anyone refer me to some code (preferably c) that would be useful in actually DRAWING it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about software engineering and not practice and performance of music. Probably more suited for Stack Exchange, or Software Recommendations.

Comment: We're also not a code-writing service, and you've not provided any evidence that you've *tried* anything.

Comment: Which development environment are you using/used?

Comment: Why not use existing open source software that already does this?

Comment: Please see answer posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366924/code-to-color-waveforms-by-frequency